# check for 'item not in mylist' causes python to crash

Tags: python, list, iteration, testcomplete

Good evening,

I am trying to build a list of backpointers. In there, I want to avoid duplicates. As far as i know i cant use a dict or set, because the items to be stored are not hashable. I implented the following code:

```
while k in range(limit):
    try:
        if path not in path_backp:
            path_backp.append(path)
            continue
        else:
            Log.Message(path.Item[k].Text)
            path = path.Item[k].Items
            limit = path.Count                
            scan(path, path_backp, e, 0)
            k = k +1
    except AttributeError:
        path = path_backp.pop()
        limit = path.Count
        k = k + 1
```

the part to avoid double entities of course is:

```
if path not in path_backp:
     path_backp.append(path)
     continue
else:
     [...]
```

Im running python inside TestComplete, which has (limited) debugging functions.
When I enable the debugger and track what is happening, the first check works. The `if`-routine gets executed, and because `path_backp` is an empty `dict`, `path` gets appended, so that afterwards `path_backp[0]` equals `path` and I get back to to the `while`-routine.
But when the `if`-routine gets executed the 2nd time (so when `path_backp` is no empty `dict` anymore), the debugger freezes for what seems an infinite amount of time.

same happens, by the way, when I implemented:

```
if path not in path_backp:
    path_backp.append(path)
```

without any `continue` or `else`.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how I can handle the situation?

Many thanks,

b.

Comment: could you post, the content of your intitial `path`?

Comment: @Remi: the `path` is pointing to an `VCLobject`. i can not specify it, due to company restrictions, but it looks like this: `Sys.Process("XXX").[...].[...].[...].wItems`

Comment: You should probably [contact TestComplete support](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) about this.